# User profile - if user logs out after saving an Asset - Invalid subpath “profile/{{currentUser.id}}” - SSO Login fails

Tags: craft3, plugin-development

Having tested this error only occurs while using the SAML Service provider plugin: I have tested in multiple versioning env and experienced the same issue.

I can save an asset file Image or doc while logged in the first time but if I log back in into via screen displays a server error and receive the below stack trace.
If I remove the asset file I am able to use SSO login again.

**Current ENV:**
Craft Pro 3.7.38
Yii 2.0.45
Twig 2.14.13
SAML Service Provider 2.7.3

**Stack Trace**

```
Next craft\errors\InvalidSubpathException: The Directory Photo field’s Asset Location setting has an invalid subpath (“profile/{{currentUser.id}}”). in /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/Assets.php:929
Stack trace:
#0 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/Assets.php(501): craft\fields\Assets->_determineUploadFolderId()
#1 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/Assets.php(565): craft\fields\Assets->craft\fields\{closure}()
#2 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Element.php(4142): craft\fields\Assets->afterElementSave()
#3 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/User.php(1617): craft\base\Element->afterSave()
#4 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Elements.php(2703): craft\elements\User->afterSave()
#5 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Elements.php(784): craft\services\Elements->_saveElementInternal()
#6 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/flipboxfactory/saml-sp/src/services/login/User.php(168): craft\services\Elements->saveElement()
#7 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/flipboxfactory/saml-sp/src/services/login/User.php(145): flipbox\saml\sp\services\login\User->save()
#8 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/flipboxfactory/saml-sp/src/services/Login.php(68): flipbox\saml\sp\services\login\User->sync()
#9 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/flipboxfactory/saml-sp/src/controllers/LoginController.php(118): flipbox\saml\sp\services\Login->transformToUser()
#10 [internal function]: flipbox\saml\sp\controllers\LoginController->actionIndex()
#11 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#12 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#13 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#14 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(293): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#15 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction()
#16 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(278): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#17 /home/umhbweb/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
#18 /home/umhbweb/craft/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved! This appeared to be a Dynamic Subfolder Paths issue

if you replace {{ currentUser.id }} with {{id}} then user is able to login and logout using sso after saving assets.